# regex how to read all the characters between the two braces

Tags: java, regex-group

I am reading log file and have to extract all the values in a line which is like below

```
>    DE-055  LLL[136] 
> CHR(_*.....\............B........(............................................12345678.&..g..2%.$.'...3.`(..4.....5.!.6....7.s$...A......S..)
```

I am trying to use regex to extract the data between the two braces (). Please advise how can I extract so far, I have tried different methods but not able to do so

```
for (String s : incomingmessage) {
    // **DE-011  FXD[006]  CHR(008432)**
    pattern3 working 
    String pattern3 = "(DE\\W\\d*)(\\s*\\w*\\W*)(\\d*)(\\W*\\s*)  (\\w*)(\\()([\\w*\\s*]+)(\\))"; --> works when the value is like above,same code do not work for the below format 

    //DE-055  LLL[136]  CHR(_*.....\............B........(............................................12345678.&..g..2%.$.'...3.`(..4.....5.!.6....7.s$...A......S..)

    String pattern3 = "(DE\\W\\d*)(\\s*\\w*\\W*)(\\d*)(\\W*\\s*)(\\w*)(\\([.*?]\\))"; --> tried many times changing not able to get the regex which will work to get the values between the two braces even if it is some funny characters like the above

    Pattern p3 = Pattern.compile(pattern3);
    // Matcher m1 = p1.matcher(s);
    //Matcher m2 = p2.matcher(s);
    Matcher m3 = p3.matcher(s);

    while (m3.find()) {
        String fullvalue = m3.group(0);
        // String field = m3.group(1);
        //String length = m3.group(3);
        //String value = m3.group(7);
        System.out.println("m3.find() full value " + fullvalue);
        //System.out.println("m3.find() filed value " + field + "length " + length + "value" + value);
    }
}
```

I want the output value as below which is between the two braces ()

```
_*.....\............B........(............................................12345678.&..g..2%.$.'...3.`(..4.....5.!.6....7.s$...A......S..
```

Comment: What value do you want?

Comment: i think we'll need more info on what each regex group would be holding.

Comment: @Tyler i want to extract "_*.....\............B........(............................................12345678.&..g..2%.$.'...3.`(..4.....5.!.6....7.s$...A......S.." which is between two () braces.

Comment: Does this help -> https://regex101.com/r/ogwLNq/2 ?

Comment: @ElliottFrisch i have updated to show what value i want

Answer (score 0):

If you don't expect nested braces, this will work:

```
String input = "sfasdf(sfsdfs76868)dslf()js98(sds),cn,";
String regex = "(?<=\\().*?(?=\\))";
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(regex);
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(input);

while (matcher.find()) {
    System.out.println("Match: " + matcher.group(0));
}
```

The output will be:

```
Match: sfsdfs76868
Match: 
Match: sds
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 String t = "DE-055  LLL[136]  CHR(_*.....\\............B........(............................................12345678.&..g..2%.$.'...3.`(..4.....5.!.6....7.s$...A......S..)";


String pattern3 = "(DE\\W\\d*)(\\s*\\w*\\W*)(\\d*)(\\W*\\s*)(\\w*)(\\()([\\W*?\\w*?\\s*?\\W*?]+)(\\))";

Output :

group 0 :   DE-055  LLL[136]  CHR(_*.....\............B........(............................................12345678.&..g..2%.$.'...3.`(..4.....5.!.6....7.s$...A......S..)
group 1 ;   DE-055
group 2 :     LLL[
group 3 :   136
group 4 :   ]  
group 5 :   CHR
group 6 :   (
group 7 :   _*.....\............B........(............................................12345678.&..g..2%.$.'...3.`(..4.....5.!.6....7.s$...A......S..
group 8 :   )
```

The group 7 gives the output which I look for.
Thanks everyone who try to help me.